# standard Java class that takes java.lang.Readable as input parameter?

Tags: java, io

I have a class (high performance file reader) that implements `java.lang.Readable`.

how can I make use of it?

I have found zero classes in the JDK that take a Readable as input (e.g., to convert it into something more generally useful). does such a thing exist?

Background:

I wrote a simple CSV reader that I would like to improve the performance of. Then I found a class from another project that maintains 2 buffers, writes to one of those buffers in a background thread, then flips to the other buffer once the first is full, and does the same. From the outside is looks like any other Readable, but the wonderful magical thing about it is this background thread makes sure that you are *almost* always reading from memory when you access this `Readable`. I want that. (At present my CSV reader uses a BufferedReader, and hence uses the Reader interface)

thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I added Background to the question

Comment: By definition a Readable must be able to create a CharBuffer. CharBuffers are pretty useful. (It's also a good idea to check on how useful a class will be *before* you implement it.)

Comment: [Uses of Interface java.lang.Readable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Readable.html) -- "A `Readable` is a source of characters. Characters from a `Readable` are made available to callers of the read method via a `CharBuffer`." [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html)

Comment: @DJClayworth I did not implement this class, I found it in another open source project

Comment: Still not clear; what is your API? From the doc, it seems that `Readable` is a "subinterface"; there are indeed no direct callers.

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks, I read the docs too. I was hoping a convenience class existed that did something like take the Readable and implement Reader, using the CharBuffers returned by the Readable to implement methods like readLine()

Answer (score 1):

There's is one class    `java.util.Scanner`     which take     `Readable`     as the parameter for one of its constructor.

Check this out
[java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html/)